# I can not select the element in iframe (I dont know it is iframe or not but it is like pop-up page) in Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am quite new to Python Selenium so I searched the problem but I cannot find the answer.

I have a website that I want to entry some data with Selenium. You can see a screen shot of the web site below.

[I had to censor some parts due to privacy of my client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUahF.png)

I can click the button indicated by the red arrow "1" in the image. After this action, website opens a pop-up page (maybe it is iframe I dont know what it is) and I want to select an item from "ITEM" dropbox and click the button indicated by the red arrow "2" in the image.
The HTML code of the relevant of the element:

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ComboName-container" title="Seçiniz">Seçiniz</span>
```

The whole HTML of the relevant of the element:

```
<div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span><b>ITEM &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</b>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="input-icon right">
                            <i class="fa"></i>
                            <select class="form-control select2" data-val="true" data-val-required="Bu alanın doldurulması zorunludur." id="ComboName-container" name="ComboName-container" required="required"><option value="">Se&#231;iniz</option>
<option value="10112">Option 1</option>
<option value="20485">Option 2</option>
<option value="21824">Option 3</option>
<option value="30474">Option 4</option>
<option value="93340">Option 5</option>
</select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Selenium can not find any element located on this pop-up page. I have `NoSuchElementException` error. Do I have to specify the pop-up page to Selenium. If answer is "Yes" How can I do it?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: @DebanjanB What about now?

Comment: What code did you use that resulted in NoSuchElement exception ?

Comment: @cruisepandey `el = Browser.find_element_by_id("select2-ComboName-container")`

Comment: can you put some delay before this line of code ? it that works we can replace time with explicit wait. put simply like time.sleep(2) , or is it possible to share URL ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I tried 3 seconds but didnt work :(

Comment: okay, please check in HTMLDOM, if it is in iframe ? just scroll up in HTML where you have this id `select2-ComboName-container`

Comment: You probably need to switch to the frame. Try `driver.switch_to.frame(frames_web_element)` before you access the element in the frame. If it works remember to switch back to the default content if you require  using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: @EbJ Do I need to have the name of the frame? I mean you used "frames_web_element" is it name of the your frame?

Comment: @AhmetÇöl That is the element itself eg `frames_web_element = Browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')`